# how to set 'ItemNullValueHandling' value dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am have requirement about to show property in response base on the class property value.If we are initializing the class by default all the properties all initializing. so, I want to ignore the properties based on the property.

Here is my class

```
[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    Public class Student
    {
     public string name{get; set;}
    public string address{get;set;}
    public bool success{get;set;}
    }
```

In the above class, Based on the value of **success**.I have to decide to show the properties in response even if they are null

I thought one solution was keeping

> [JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]

but dynamically i have to set the value of **ItemNullValueHandling** i didn't know that how to set dynamically can any one please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to dynamically change the serialisation settings using attributes as they are fixed at compile time.

However, you can pass an instance of JsonSerializerSettings to the Deserialize() method as shown below.

```cs
    var showAllProperties = student.success;
    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
        NullValueHandling = showAllProperties ? NullValueHandling.Include : NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    }
    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student, serializerSettings)
```